# Undefined offset in while loop with 2 conditions

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I have an array like this :

```
array (size=3)
 0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'score' => float 17.891873624039
 1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'score' => float 17.883449353824
 2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'score' => float 4.702030124427
```

and have a while loop like this:

```
 $offset=1;
 while($scoreList[$rank+$offset]!=NULL && $scoreList[$rank]["score"]==$scoreList[$rank+$offset]["score"])
 {
    //do something
    $offset++;
 }
```

I need to check if the next index in the array exists and at the same time check if it is equal to the current object but I get

> Undefined offset:4

I cannot put the second condition in an if statement because offset should be increased if these two indexes are equal so it falls in an infinite loop if I put it in if clause.

Comment: Google for `isset();` and/or `empty();`

Comment: @Epodax empty() solved the issue thanks. write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properly these two could be useful :)

`isset();` - [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if(isset($value[0])){
  //DO SOMETHING IF VALUE IS SET
}

if(!isset($value[0])){
  //DO SOMETHING IF VALUE ISN'T SET
}
```

`empty();` - [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
if(empty($value[0])){
  //DO SOMETHING IF VALUE / VARIABLE DOESN'T EXIST
}

if(!empty($value[0])){
  //DO SOMETHING IF VALUE / VARIABLE DOES EXIST AND ISN'T EMPTY
}
```

Comment: `!empty` itself check that value `isset` and `not empty`

Comment: so I changed  `$scoreList[$rank+$offset]!=NULL` to `!empty($scoreList[$rank+$offset])` and it worked